# Android: Scrolling from one Fragment to another through a ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have implemented a ViewPager which connects multiple Fragments together to give off that 'scrolling view' experience as you might already know. Anyhow I have a button on my first fragment that needs to scroll the user to the second fragment. How do I get this done folks? Here's my code:

ViewPager XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
</LinearLayout>
```

Fragment 1:

```
<RelativeLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#3498db" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:text="Step 1"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:textSize="50dp" />

                <Button
                android:id="@+id/step1Btn"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5sp"
                android:background="@drawable/buttonshape"
                android:shadowColor="#A8A8A8"
                android:shadowDx="0"
                android:shadowDy="0"
                android:shadowRadius="5"
                android:text="Next Step"
                android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
```

In order to make this post short, let's say the second fragment has the same XML.

So we have TWO fragments. Here's the fragment java class:

```
public class RegisterPageOne extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        final View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.registration_page1, container, false);

        Button nextStep = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.step1Btn);
        nextStep.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //Where I want to call the SECOND FRAG
            }
        });

        return v;
    }


    public static RegisterPageOne newInstance(String text) {

        RegisterPageOne f = new RegisterPageOne();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putString("msg", text);

        f.setArguments(b);

        return f;
    }
}
```

help me out please :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the setCurrentItem(int item,boolean smoothScroll) method of your viewPager object to achieve this. [Here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setCurrentItem(int,%20boolean)) is the documentation.

Comment: Problem is, the button is in the fragment's XML. So how am I supposed to refer to the ViewPager through the fragment's java class? :)

Comment: You can simply pass the Viewpager object as a parameter in the constructor of your fragment and use it!!

Answer (score 0):

Saw your followup question about how to refer to the ViewPager, from your Fragment. It's pretty convoluted, for a relative newbie like me, but, I think I can get all of it... I'll give you what I did in my code. Set up a listener in the ViewPager:

public class PageViewActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements PageDisplayPortFrag.OnLinkExpectedListener {
    ...
    }

This gets referenced in your Fragment:

```
private OnLinkExpectedListener mListenerLink;

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);

    try {
        mListenerLink = (OnLinkExpectedListener) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(activity.toString()
                + " must implement OnLinkExpectedListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    mListenerLink = null;
    super.onDetach();
}

// THIS IS THE METHOD CALLED BY THE BUTTON CLICK !!!
public void linkExpected(String ticker) {
    if (mListenerLink != null) {
        mListenerLink.onLinkActivity(ticker);
    }
}

public interface OnLinkExpectedListener {

    public void onLinkActivity(String ticker);
}
```

And, then, a method gets called in the ViewPager:

```
@Override
public void onLinkActivity(String ticker) {
    // receive ticker from port click; user wants to view page in webview, for this security

    //Toast.makeText(this, "Ticker item clicked: " + ticker, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    // NEHARA, YOU MAY OR MAY NOT NEED TO DO STUFF HERE
    // THIS IS WHAT I NEEDED TO DO; LEAVING IT FOR THE 
    // getFragmentTag() EXAMPLE -- WHICH CAME FROM Stack Overflow POSTERS
    // get all-important fragment tag
    String frag_Tag = getFragmentTag(pager.getId(),1);
    // use tag to get the webview fragment
    PageXYZWebviewFrag xyzWeb = (PageXYZWebviewFrag)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(frag_Tag);
    // send request to the webview fragment
    xyzWeb.loadPageForSelectedSecurity(ticker);

    // SET THE DESIRED FRAGMENT, assumes I know the fragment number
    // from when I set up the ViewPager
    // switch to the webview fragment
    pager.setCurrentItem(1);
}

// fragment tag getter -- very important, yet has been elusive
private String getFragmentTag(int viewPagerId, int fragmentPosition) {
    return "android:switcher:" + viewPagerId + ":" + fragmentPosition;
}
```